# Apparent classloader leak in Play! 2.3.4

Tags: multithreading, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have walked several heap snapshots of a Play 2.3.4 application in JProfiler and VisualVM (ironically VisualVM seems to be more helpful) and have found that upon Play! reload classloaders are not properly replaced and several copies of old classloaders retaining old instances of old classes are retained in memory.  After several application reloads the application crashes with an out of memory error (heap consistently  exhausts before permanent generation probably due to the memory-intensive nature of the application).

While tracking down GC roots, I have found the following implicating evidence.  There are 4 instances of **PlayRun$$anonfun$10$$anon$2** with live objects, and as I understand there should only ever be 1 particularly noted by the observation that each of these classloader instances contains duplicate copies of my application's classes:

GC Roots of 4 **PlayRun$$anonfun$10$$anon$2** instances retained in memory by thread stack frames:

- **contextClassLoader** of *BoneCP-keep-alive-scheduler*
- **inheritedAccessControlContext** of *play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-27*
- **contextClassLoader** of *play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-32*
- **contextClassLoader** of *pool-16-thread-3* (java.util.concurrent executor service?)

Why are these other threads retaining references to obsolete Play! application classloaders?  Doesn't Play! shutdown dependent threads like these to safeguard against this?  Is it possible that some phase of the reload process failed to execute properly resulting in this bad object retention state?

The application is built on top of Play! 2.3.4 and SBT 0.13.6.  This problem *did not* occur prior to upgrading from Play! 2.2.2 / SBT 0.13.1.